# How to access public and private variable with in the static method?

Tags: php

I have problem to access the private and public variable within the static function. I know to access the static variable to access the static function.

Sample Example:

```
class Student{
public $name = "Rajkumar";
private $mark = 10;
static $result = "Pass";
static function Display(){
echo(self::$result);
//here how to access $name and $mark
}
}
```

Is this possible or not.

Comment: you can only access static variables from static functions

Answer (score 3):

You have to mark the properties as static as well. You can't access non-static properties from a static function, even if those properties have hardcoded values (like your example).